# My figures are displayed on a new page while it should fit easily on the previous page

Tags: floats

[image]When I insert 2 pictures into my script, these pictures jump to the next page when i compile the script, while it should fit on the desired page. Even implementing t, h or H into the script does not work. My code is the following:

```
\documentclass[9pt, a4paper]{article}

% standard packages
\usepackage{titlesec,color,rotating,booktabs,graphicx,natbib}    % standard packages
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames,table, xcdraw]{xcolor}          % extra colors 
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{longtable}

\usepackage{blindtext}
% PAGE MARGINS
\usepackage[top=2.54cm, bottom=2.54cm, left=3.17cm, right=3.17cm]{geometry}

% FONT (similar to Verdana)
\usepackage[lf]{berenis}
\renewcommand*\familydefault{\sfdefault} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
% for other fonts, and how to install them, see the LaTeX Font Catalogue:
% http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/

% LINE SPACE
\linespread{1.1}                          % more space between lines
\setlength{\parindent}{5mm}               % indenting first line paragraph

% HYPHENATION (afbreekstreepjes)
\usepackage[english]{babel}                                      % correct hyphenation (afbreekstreepjes)
% set words that are not abbreviated correctly  (expand list when necessary)
\hyphenation{catch-ment areas a-na-lyse}

% Blue headers
%\definecolor{wurblue}{cmyk}{1.0,0,0,0.58}
\usepackage{sectsty}
\allsectionsfont{\color{CornflowerBlue}}

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
%graphs
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{figs}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup{belowskip=0pt}
\usepackage{subcaption}


\newpage
\section{Time planning}
\begin{figure}[t!]
\centering
\begin{subfigure}{\textwidth}
\includegraphics{figs/Milestones.png}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}{\textwidth}
\includegraphics{figs/PlanningMOOI.png}
\end{subfigure}
\end{figure}
```

Any idea what is wrong?

Comment: It's hard to tell, a) without document setup, b) without knowing how much text there is, and c) without knowing how big these images are.

Comment: @Plergux I added the document setup to the question. The pictures are 15.9 and 49.9 kb, together they do cover around 0,5 pages. As shown in the code, I want these two pictures to appear on a new page with only a title above it. Does this give some clearance?

Comment: If I compile this with images that take about half a page they appear right after the header with these settings and position set to [h]. Only setting their size too high to fit the page makes them jump over to the next page. Have you tried setting an absolute size for your images with for example \includegraphics[width=5cm]{figs/Milestones.png} to see if you make them smaller they will stay on the right page?

Comment: Changing the absolute size indeed fixes the problem of the pictures jumping to the next page. However, the size of the pictures is now very limited. I am trying to expand the width to a maximum by using \paperwidth, but without any luck. Any suggestion what i can change in the code to make the pictures more clear/ (i'll add a picture of the current layout above)

Comment: did you change \begin{subfigure}{...} or \includegraphics[...]{figs/Milestones.png}? Because I don't think the width parameter with \begin{subfigure} actually changes the width of the image, only the space it is supposed to take on the page. For example if you wanted the figures side by side you could specify {0.3\textwidth} for one and {0.6\textwidth} for the other (because they are different widths). I tried setting the \includegraphics width to \textwidth (f.x. \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{figs/Milestones.png}) and it worked fine. They lined up one after the other after the heading.

Comment: You realize that [t] floats will appear above the `\section` title?  Try throwing a `\null\par` after `\section` to disable `\@afterheading`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To large to fit in comment ...

After preamble arrangements (grouping related packages, remove duplicate loads of packages) using `xelatex` and relative large demo images (`height=0.6\linewidth` and `width=0.8\linewidth`) and `ht` float placement option, I can't confirm your problem. Result is fine:

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[vmargin=2.54cm, 
            hmargin=3.17cm]{geometry}   % page layout
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}                % font encoding
\usepackage[lf]{berenis}
\renewcommand*\familydefault{\sfdefault}

\usepackage[english]{babel}             % language
% some hyphenation examples
\hyphenation{catch-ment areas a-na-lyse}

\usepackage{titlesec}                   % titles, don't use both packages!
                                        % in case that you use both, 
                                        % "titlesec" had to be before sessty
\usepackage{sectsty}

\usepackage{natbib}                     % bibliography
\usepackage[usenames, dvipsnames, svgnames, % color names
            xcdraw,table]{xcolor}       % colors
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}             % graphic, in real document remove "demo" option 
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\graphicspath{figs}

\usepackage{rotating}         
\usepackage{booktabs, 
            longtable, multirow}        % tables packages

\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup{belowskip=0pt}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\linespread{1.1}                        % more space between lines
\setlength{\parindent}{5mm}             % indenting first line paragraph

\begin{document}
%\newpage
\section{Time planning}
\blindtext
    \begin{figure}[ht]
\begin{subfigure}{\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[height=0.6\linewidth, width=0.8\linewidth]{Milestones.png}
\end{subfigure}

\begin{subfigure}{\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[height=0.6\linewidth, width=0.8\linewidth]{PlanningMOOI.png}
\end{subfigure}
    \end{figure}
\blindtext
\end{document}
```